# What is the function of Scroll Lock key on keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good is the Scroll Lock key?](https://superuser.com/questions/4443/what-good-is-the-scroll-lock-key)

I think the question explains everything. I have been using the keyboard for 10 years now. Have learnt a lot of keyboard shortcuts but till now I'm not able to make out the role/function of **Scroll Lock** button on the keyboard.

---

Any comments appreciated.

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/4443/what-good-is-the-scroll-lock-key

Answer (score 0):

I once saw scroll lock used in Excel.  Can you launch that program and test it yourself?  Most other programs don't use it.  One other thing, it sometimes flashes in boot sequences, the flashes help in troubleshooting startup problems.

That said I cannot get Scroll lock to do anything in Excel 2007.

Comment: It does what it should do. Make the cursor keys move the viewport, not the selection.

Comment: Scroll lock is working on all Excel versions, even the newest ones like 2013 or 2016. Probably you have disabled something